# iOS drawrect ios6 v ios7

Tags: ios, uiview, drawrect, cgcontext, ipad-mini

I have an app that basically is a ring size app, I have stored all the CGRect frames in an array and then I pass them into a UIView class. So you can navigate through the array changing the size of the circle.

Works fine on all iOS7 devices, however on an iPad 3 running iOS6 the circle is displaying a different size to that of an iPad mini running iOS7.

What would be causing the discrepancy?

My drawrect code is as follows:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 0);

    CGRect circlePoint = arect;
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, circlePoint);

    CGColorSpaceRef baseSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGGradientRef gradient = [UIColorFromRGB(0xecc7da) newGradientToColor:UIColorFromRGB(0xcc6699)];
    CGColorSpaceRelease(baseSpace), baseSpace = NULL;

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, arect);
    CGContextClip(context);

    CGPoint gradCenter = CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height/2);
    float gradRadius = MIN(arect.size.width , arect.size.height) ;

    CGContextDrawRadialGradient (context, gradient, gradCenter, 0, gradCenter, gradRadius, kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation);

    CGGradientRelease(gradient), gradient = NULL;

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, arect);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);
}
```

Ok so an update, here is myView.h file :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface myView : UIView{
CGRect arect;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame shaperect:(CGRect)shaperect;

@end
```

And .m file:

```
#import "myView.h"
#import "UIColor+EasyGradients.h"

@implementation myView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame shaperect:(CGRect)shaperect;
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

        arect = shaperect;

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 0);

    CGRect circlePoint = arect;
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, circlePoint);

    CGColorSpaceRef baseSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGGradientRef gradient = [UIColorFromRGB(0xecc7da) newGradientToColor:UIColorFromRGB(0xcc6699)];
    CGColorSpaceRelease(baseSpace), baseSpace = NULL;

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, arect);
    NSLog(@"x = %f | y = %f | w = %f | h = %f", arect.origin.x, arect.origin.y, arect.size.width, arect.size.height);
    CGContextClip(context);

    CGPoint gradCenter = CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height/2);
    float gradRadius = MIN(arect.size.width , arect.size.height) ;

    CGContextDrawRadialGradient (context, gradient, gradCenter, 0, gradCenter, gradRadius, kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation);


    CGGradientRelease(gradient), gradient = NULL;

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, arect);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);

}
```

That file gets called and used from my viewcontroller whos .m code is something like this:

```
myView *myViewx = [[myView alloc] initWithFrame: container shaperect:  CGRectFromString([arrayofRects objectForKey:@"0"])];
    myViewx.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    myViewx.tag = 7;

    [self.view addSubview:myViewx];
```

Comment: In iOS7 you have 20 more pixels to spend because of the statusbar. Have you made sure that is calculated correctly?

Comment: Would that affect my code above?

Comment: It could depending on the rect you input into this function. Log it to be sure. Also your using the bounds.size.height, so yeah, you should look into that. You could post some images and let us see what's happening.

Comment: I only use bounds.size.height to get the x and y position for the center of the device, the height and width of circle rect are numerical values I have defined in an array, here is a screen shot...https://www.dropbox.com/s/vkpa9dqz2zd2s73/image.jpeg top one is ipad 3 ios6 and bottom is ipad mini ios7

Comment: As I suspected, the statusbar area (which is 20pxls) is used for the iOS7 version and not with the iOS6 version. However could you post a log of each of the rects that you use to draw the circles?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xtfvzjsqsja7d8q/Untitled.txt top half is log from ios6 simulator and bottom half is from ios7 simulator

Comment: I don't see any difference. Those are the 2 different iOS apps I presume. And they are all logged from the drawRect which you have an assumed problem with, right?

Comment: They are the logs from the app running ios6 and 7 on an iphone simulator, i just tried it on an ipad and the results are the same. I did log the results from my loop before drawrect, but I did just also log the results from there and they are the same......hang on one min.....i wasnt logging properly from drawrect...2 secs

Comment: Ok, I find this very odd. Could you do a test for me just to simplify things and exclude possible scenario's. Can you go to this site: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_6_iPhone_Graphics_Tutorial_using_Quartz_2D_and_Core_Image#Drawing_an_Ellipse_or_Circle. And then scroll down to the 'Drawing an Ellipse or Circle' header. Then replace your current code with the one they provide there but instead of using their predefined rect, use the one you provide from your array. Try this and provide me with the results, please.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far, I have replaced my code with that from theirs but the result is still the same. I did notice that the CGrect I passed in was different to the one that drawrect spat out, but this was consistently the same on ipad, iphone across both ios's

Comment: No problem! But we don't have a solution yet so I'm not happy yet! You should look into the difference in the rects that you just discovered. However in the meantime, can you tell me how you use this drawRect method in your app? The usage and the way of overriding might cause some problems. We do now know at least it cannot lie in the way you draw circles, which is good.

Comment: Oh, This article might be quite useful. http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=471132. Will you look into this at post me the results again? This CGContextConvertRectToDeviceSpace might just be the thing you want.

Comment: myView *myViewx = [[myView alloc] initWithFrame: container shaperect: CGRectFromString([rings objectForKey:@"0"])];

Thats how I implement the view, I have subclassed UIView and called it myView, I then send a container frame for the view to hold the circle, I then created a custom cgrect var in myView and then pass it in above from my array using CGRectFromString, if you give me your email I can send you the h and m files from the view controller and view

Comment: You can post a general version in here as well. It might help other users find the problem faster then I can. Make sure you don't post any specifics of your app. And try to generalise var-names though.

Comment: Right have posted myview code and then the basic part of my viewcontroller file that uses the rects from the array, anything obvious?

Comment: Nothing obvious. I want you to do yet another test tho. Try calling drawRect Manually in the init method, after the super init. Then call the [self setNeedsDisplay] and see what happens. Post the results here again.

Comment: ok, so I changed it to this: - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame shaperect:(CGRect)shaperect;
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        
        arect = shaperect;
        
        [self drawRect:shaperect];
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
        
    }
    return self;
} 

and I got some warnings : <Error>: CGContextSetLineWidth: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error.

Comment: Mmm, try it with the code from the earlier link, if that won't work either then my gamble didn't pay of. Also try leaving out that 'arect' var altogether and just use the rect value from the parameter in drawrect.

Comment: right calling [self drawRect:shaperect]; passes in the rect from my viewcontroller and then passes the rect into drawrect, but then drawrect gets called again with an x and y of 0 and a width and height of 200 which is my container size. But the circle no longer changes size

Comment: What if you let your rect from the array decide the dimensions of the view?

Comment: have done that, changed the drawing code back to mine as the techtopia one had a stroke that was clipping round the edges, now there is a circle changing size again on the view, but its x and y are off, so i need to correct that to be in the middle, then I need to check all the sizes are right as before on my phone then deploy to an ios6 ipad and check\

Comment: only problem is now is my circle is clipped slightly along all edges and not sure how to padd that so it doesnt?

Comment: I've read some article about that somewhere. Does setting the property .clipToBounds = NO; help you?

Comment: That made no difference to the clipping around the edges, here is a screen shot:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/mwreupu54gffh6b/Screenshot%202014-04-01%2016.12.38.png

Comment: Does this happen on both iOS versions?

Comment: Yes it does, it is odd as first one that loads in is as the screen grab, but then others when i change the size seem to not have the squaring of the edges but then others do, odd

Comment: This didn't work for you did it? https://github.com/superjohan/circlo/blob/master/Classes/Circle.m
Also can you post a link with a circle that does look like what you want/need.

Comment: Nope that doenst affect it at all, https://www.dropbox.com/s/ke4ht3j2fqo3j6i/Screenshot%202014-04-01%2012.02.17.png is an example of the circle, but thats not my problem, my problem is that using the same code on ios6/7 produces a different sized circle on the devices

this file contains an array of the cgrects as strings https://www.dropbox.com/s/xtfvzjsqsja7d8q/Untitled.txt

Comment: And is that problem solved now? Or what is the deal with it next?

Comment: My problems now are 2 fold, my original problem of on an ipad 3 ios6 a circle is bigger than on an ipad mini ios7, and now that I have changed my code to just use the one CGRect it now clips the circle on the edges.

Comment: So all these changes did nothing to solve at least that rect problem . I can't find anything obvious and with all tricks that I knew and found we can't get it to work properly. It might as well be something Apple did within the UIKit so that the methods your using to fill a rect with a circle are working differently on both iOS versions. But I couldn't find evidence to that either.

Comment: Effectively I want to draw a circle of a set size, any size, and it be the same "physical" size on any device, retina, non retina, ios6 or 7. Why am I finding it so hard?

Comment: What is odd is this...I have done a screen grab of the app running under iphone 5 ios7, ipad 3 ios7, simulator retina ipad ios6, simulator ipad non retina ios6 and then put the screen grabs into photoshop and ALL of the circles match in size identically, so what could possibly be wrong with the device that is showing it incorrectly?

Comment: Perhaps it is all just in your mind then? Maybe it appears different when its actually not. The screenshots give you proof of that. You can't say you (or me) haven't tried everything to make the illusion disappear, and I'm sure that if this is just an illusion then you can convince your superiors of the same thing.

Comment: how does it explain this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vkpa9dqz2zd2s73/image.jpeg ??

Comment: The longer I stare at it, the more I hesitate. They seem so similar. And since I'm not physically there, it is hard to judge.

Comment: But they are different sizes. As they have a circle cut out that is the S version and they have overlayed that on the device and is fine on ipad mini but then overlaying the same cut out circle on the ipad 3 and the circle on the ipad 3 is bigger!

Comment: Can you make a screen grab from the actual device and check it the same way you did with the simulators?

Comment: I have asked and will report back the results!